# setediting = true on tableview makes cell accessoryview disappear?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UISwitchView on every tableview cell, and would like to allow the cells to be reordered. The problem is when I set setEditing=true on the table view, the accessory (switchview) disappears. Is there a way to keep both?

**EDIT**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Edit Sources Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
} 

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
Source *source = [self.sources objectAtIndex:row];

cell.textLabel.text = source.name;

UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
switchView.tag = row;
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView setOn:source.switchedOn animated:NO];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChangedForSource:)  forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged] ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UITableViewCell has an additional property, `editingAccessoryView`, for a view that is displayed when the cell is in editing mode.

I don't know if you can assign the same UISwitch instance to both the `accessoryView` and `editingAccessoryView` properties, or if you will need to make two instances. (A view can only have one parent at a time, but the UITableViewCell is actually doing the work of displaying the view, so it may be smart enough to handle this case.)

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is way to keep them.

you should make **a custom cell view**, **you can add every UI elements to this custom cell**, including the switch view  (or anything else) and **you won't be problem** when you set the editing true of the table, because on the custom cell view the UI elements won't disappear.

the standard table cells's UI elements are being controlled by not you this is why you can see only one of the built-in accessories at same time. it will never happen when you use custom cell views.

I hope you are familiar with the custom cell views but if you are not, I can provide exact code as well but the idea would be this.

Comment: I believe Im currently using a custom cell view (from storyboard). I've added the switchview as the custom cell's accessory type

see edit to my question

Comment: okay, what I did is working fine: 
1. set the `Style` to `Custom`;
2. added the switch view to the custom cell;
3. set both the `Accessory` and 'Editing Acc.` to `None`; and
4. the switch view does not disappear after the `[self.tableview setEditing:true]`...

it is hard to say why it is wrong at you because I'm not seeing the UI settings in the interface builder.

Comment: Just don't set `cell.accessoryView` at all. Add your own subview inside `cell.contentView`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that it is disappearing **under** the reorder control, you can have it relocate to a different place by adjusting the `autoresizingMask` property if you're adding the switch in code, or by adjusting the Autosizing graphically if you've built it in IB.

Comment: i've tried mving its frame, setting autoresizing mask, but it doesnt appear AT ALL. it seems that setting editing size = true is setting accessoryView to none?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subclass your tableview cell. To programatically move the `UISwitch` to the left if `self.isEditing` is YES for your `UITableViewCell` subclass.